# ANDROID - RatingBar in ListView example required for send data into MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, listview, ratingbar

I am just a beginner in programming languages android, my project obtained from internet, and now i got the code to display a value from `MySQL` and using `RatingBar` for send the value of `ratingbar` itself, and i need help how to use it!

can someone explain how to use `ratingbar` in `listview`??

i'd create a layout like this :

```js
|------------------|
| TextView         | ---> Questionare question obtained from server (id 1)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value
|------------------|
| TextView         | ---> Questionare question obtained from server (id 2)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value 
|------------------|
| TextView         | ---> Questionare question obtained from server (id 3)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value
|__________________|
```

and this is a few code i've tried to displayed the `ratingbar` in `listview`

`AsyncTask doInBackground`

```js
HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String url = "http://****.com/send_data.php";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");

                        HashMap<String, String> pertanyaans = new HashMap<>();

                        pertanyaans.put("id", id);
                        pertanyaans.put("ask", ask);

                        contactList.add(pertanyaans);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Pertanyaan.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_pertanyaan, new String[]{"ask", "id"}, new int[]{R.id.ask, R.id.txtid});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**My problem** is how i know which ratingbar in the list is `onTouch`?

and sending any rating bar value that was filled from the `listview` to the server?

> **i've try to find any tutorial from internet, but the tutorial is so scrimpy**

Answer (score 0):

Create class that is extended by BaseAdapter then in getView() method identify rating bar and then there you have to set touch listener for rating bar.