# ANDROID - using RatingBar in ListView to send data at MySQL

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

> I'm just newbie about Android and sorry if my question is not valuable

i've create a layout like this :

```js
|------------------|
| TextView         | ---> Text obtained from server (id 1)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value
|------------------| ---> ListView
| TextView         | ---> Text obtained from server (id 2)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value 
|------------------| ---> ListView
| TextView         | ---> Text obtained from server (id 3)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value
|                  |
|    |Button|      |
|__________________|
```

My problem is : how to send all Rating when the `RatingBar` already got the star using `Button`

Reference :

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326609/android-how-to-use-ratingbar-in-listview-to-send-data-into-mysql) (i don't know why i should use `getView()` when i just need to send all rating into server)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769375/android-required-example-for-using-ratingbar-in-listview) (tired to find ViewBinder example for my app)
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829587/android-ratingbar-in-listview-example-required-for-send-data-into-mysql)

**The tutorial for `RatingBar` is so scrimpy on net, so i need help here**

Comment: In a listview you have items with ratingbar, now after doing changes in ratings you want to send updated rating to server on click of button. Is it like so?

Comment: @ReadyAndroid yes sir, i have an item with ratingbar in listview, but not when ratings change, the ratings in my app just like an `answer`, so any value in ratings should `insert` to server when `button` clicked

Comment: @ReadyAndroid im using `ListView` for my app, and is it allowed by the rules in SOF sir?

Comment: I am giving solution for your question. Which is easy for others if they are having same issue in future.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid it's ok if we're not breaking the rule, thanks anyway