# RatingBar in listview to send a value into server (MySQL)

Tags: android, mysql, listview, ratingbar

> I'm just new about android programming and i need help! [About what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/): i've tried to find a tutorial to send data into server through `ratingbar` in `listview`, but its too **scrimpy**!

i have created an app, and this is a pieces of layout in my app:

```
|------------------|
| TextView         | ---> Text obtained from server (id 1)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value
|------------------| ---> ListView
| TextView         | ---> Text obtained from server (id 2)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value 
|------------------| ---> ListView
| TextView         | ---> Text obtained from server (id 3)
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar the value
|                  |
|    |Button|      |
|__________________|
```

**My Question**: how to send all the value of `ratingbar` into server?

i'd read about `getView()` `ViewHolder` and etc, but I still do not know the usefulness nor how to use of those, and i know it was related to my issue

i have a logic/algorithm like:

```js
if (ratingbar value==5){
  call the url 'insert 5'
  }
else if (ratingbar value==4){
  call the url 'insert 4'
  }
else if (ratingbar value==3){
  call the url 'insert 3'
  }
else if (ratingbar value==2){
  call the url 'insert 2'
  }
else if (ratingbar value==1){
  call the url 'insert 1'
  }
else{
  printout"Rating cannot be null"
  }
```

but I do not know how to put it into the android, ***can someone help me out?***

Comment: you should make use of list view positions to get values

Comment: @Eswar do you have a reference how to use listview position? i just learn an android a few month,

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: @Eswar oh man, i dont know the function of each class except MainActivity, i mean what the function of Movie class in their tutorial?

Comment: I'm sorry for complex guide. I suggest you to try this step by step 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-itemclicklistener-for-a-listview-with-images-and-text/

Comment: @Eswar thanks for the reference, ill try it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANDROID - using RatingBar in ListView to send data at MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862971/android-using-ratingbar-in-listview-to-send-data-at-mysql)